# Pegar o valor da variável Jquery fora do if

Tags: jquery

Estou montando um script que faz a verificação de vários inputs select, verificando se os mesmos foram selecionados.
Estou no início, por isso o exemplo aqui  tem apenas um campo.

```js
$("#passo_4").click(function(){
  if($("#horario_ini_seg option:selected").val() == ''){
    var his = 0;
   } else{
    var his = 1;
  }  
});   
alert(his);
```

Se eu colocar o alert embaixo de cada var, funciona.
Se eu colocar fora, não funciona.

Se der certo, quero fazer uma var, somando todos os valores.
Se der 0, é que precisa preencher algum dos campos, senão, passa para a próxima tela.
Tem um checkbox que preciso fazer o mesmo, mas creio que seja o mesmo caso.

São 14 inputs.

Minha ideia é fazer a verificação de todos no evento click.

Mas não entendi por que ele não pega o valor do jeito que fiz.

Comment: você está declarando a variável dentro do if  por isso só funciona embaixo de cada valor

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você está declarando a variável dentro de uma função no `click` por isso só funciona o alert dentro do `$("#passo_4").click(function(){});`

```js
 var his = 0;
$("#passo_4").click(function(){
  
  if($("#horario_ini_seg option:selected").val() == ''){
     his = 0;
   } else{
     his = 1;
  } 
  alert(his); 
});
```

Comment: Deu certo. Muito obrigado!!

Comment: Não foi nada !!

Answer (score 2):

Explicação do problema:
Se você declarou a variavel his dentro do if ou do else é indiferente o problema é que a variavel `his` no seu código só existe dentro do escopo da função do seu click `$("#passo_4").click(function(){});`.

```js
var his;

$("#passo_4").click(function(){
  if($("#horario_ini_seg option:selected").val() == ''){
    his = 0;
   }else{
    his = 1;
  }  
});  

alert(his); //Só será exibido quando carregar e trará o valor  inicial nesse caso undefined

//Criei o bloco abaixo só para demonstrar o alert com a variavel his fora do evento click do botão passo_4:
$("#passo_5").click(function(){
  alert(his);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" id="passo_4">Pedir café</button>
<select name="horario_ini_seg" id="horario_ini_seg">
  <option value="">Café forte</option>
  <option value="Zuado">Café fraco</option>
</select>
<button type="button" id="passo_5">Exibe variavel his</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Amigo, o problema é que sua variavel his está fora da função click! Declare a variavel his fora do contexto do click que funciona

```
var his = 0;
$("#passo_4").click(function(){
  if($("#horario_ini_seg option:selected").val() == ''){
    var his = 0;
   }    else{
    var his = 1;
  }     
});         
alert(his);
```